# convert logarithmic value to linear (xc8)

Tags: pic, xc8

I am intending to use the ADC in a PIC16F family device to 'convert' the input from a logarithmic output sensor to a linear scale so I can present it (as a 'linear binary value') on the PIC's PORT, albeit with a reduced resolution.

There is some example code in the sensor manual for an Arduino -

```
float RawToLux(int raw)
{
float logLux = raw * logRange / rawRange;
return pow(10, logLux);
}
```

Is there something similar available in XC8 (Microchip's C compiler)? I have looked but there seems to be only functions for converting linear values to log, or am I being silly?

Regards
Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the xc8 compiler user guide. The pow function is also included. Something like:

```
#include <math.h>
double logRange = ...;
double rawRange = ...; 

double RawToLux(int raw)
{
    double logLux = raw * logRange / rawRange;
    return pow(10.0, logLux);
}
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will try that (apologies I didn't expect similar functions would be available in xc8)

Comment: don't forget to include <math.h> though